# how to get xpath href in a dense html tree

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, xpath, lxml

I am trying to get `href` data for the below url

```
url = r'https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/?term=COVID-19&filter=simsearch1.fha&page=1'
```

using below code

```
lxml.html.fromstring(url).xpath('//div[contains(@class,"inner-wrap")]//div/a[contains(@class,"labs-docsum-title")]//@href')
```

i have tried a number of other alternatives for the string inside the xpath such as

```
.xpath('.//div/a/@href')
```

and

```
.xpath(r'/html/body/main/div[8]/div[2]/section/div[1]/div/article[1]/div[2]/div[1]/a[1]/@href')
```

but i get an empty `[]` every time. I believe that I am not getting the hierarchy (parent-child) tree correct but not able to figure out what is wrong. My desired solution could look something like:

```
print(href)
"/32139372/?from_term=COVID-19&from_filter=simsearch1.fha&from_page=1&from_pos=1"
```

for the fist item in the iteration

Comment: There are 10 or so links in there; do you only need the first?

Comment: yes. only the first. I can get the remaining with the loop. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
url = "https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/?term=COVID-19&filter=simsearch1.fha&page=1"
resp = requests.get(url)
doc = lxml.html.fromstring(resp.text)
links = doc.xpath('//div/a[@class="labs-docsum-title"]')
print(links[0].attrib.get('href'))
```

Output:

```
/32139372/?from_term=COVID-19&from_filter=simsearch1.fha&from_page=1&from_pos=1
```